# How to return an object from a Collection.

Tags: java, list, collections

```
class Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    //Overriding equals() and hashCode() to just field x
}

List<Foo> myList=new ArrayList<Foo>();

myList.add(fooObj);
myList.add(fooObj2);
```

All my *Foo* objects are basically compared based on field x.

I would like to get *fooObj* from the list based on value x. Why it doesn’t make sense to add a method say `get(Object o)` instead of work around of doing a `list.get(list.indexOf(fooObj))` to get the complete object from the list. `indexOf()` can return "**null**" so a null check is needed which is not good as well.

**UPDATE**:

Map will be a good idea to have a key value pair of getX() -> objFoo. If my Foo is defined by two fields say X and Y of Foo class then **Map cannot be used for this purpose.**

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to retrieve objects in this way (basically using partial instances of Foo as keys to retrieve the stored instances), you're probably well advised to consider looking at a keyed collection - like `Set<Foo>`

Comment: Set is all the more worse. You cant even get an object like the way list can be done using IndexOf() method and then apply a get().

Comment: Why couldn't you create a pair object containing y and z and store that in the map?

Comment: "If my Foo is defined by two fields say X and Y of Foo class then Map cannot be used for this purpose."  Sure it can, you just need to create a key type with those two fields, and that's still probably cleaner than the alternatives.

Comment: "`indexOf()` can return null" . `get(Object o)` shall return a *null* value too,am I right?

Comment: `indexOf` cannot return `null` as primitive types are not objects. [It returns `-1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) if it does not contain the element, and passing that to `get(int)` would result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Map<Foo, Foo>` instead:

```
Map<Foo, Foo> map = new HashMap<Foo, Foo>();
// Store
map.put(fooObj, fooObj);
// Retrieve
map.get(fooObj2); // => fooObj
```

Although I think overriding `equals` is not a very good solution for this use case. Your `equals` override treats `fooObj` and `fooObj2` as "equal", but your application wants them to be treated as different in some place. These conflicts will sooner or later back-fire, introduce bugs and give you headaches.

I'd rather separate the identifier from the data and give `Foo` a `FooKey` field.

```
class FooKey {
    final int x;

    public FooKey(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    // TODO Override equals and hashCode to only compare FooKeys on x field
}

class Foo {
    final FooKey id;
    int y;
    int z;

    public Foo(FooKey id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Your application code then becomes much easier to understand:

```
Map<FooKey, Foo> map = new ArrayList<FooKey, Foo>();
// Store
Foo fooObj = new Foo(new FooKey(123));
map.put(fooObj.id, fooObj);
// Retrieve
map.get(fooObj.id); // => fooObj
map.get(new FooKey(123)); // also fooObj if FooKey.equals is properly overridden
```

Using a separate (composite) key field can also prove valuable when you decide you want to persist your `Foo` objects in a database. For example, JPA allows you to use an `@IdClass` or `@EmbeddedId` to let `Foo` entities be identified by `FooKey`s. This may not be relevant for your current scenario, but if you were thinking of implementing persistence some time in the future you probably want to already start considering this in your class hierarchy.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I feel like Java API should have included this sort of thing in their List implementations.

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast That's not the job of `List`, and in my opinion no class should need to do that. If you say `fooObj.equals(fooObj2)` is true if `fooObj.x == fooObj2.x`, then you *should expect* other classes to treat them *as equal*. Many classes rely on this and if you attempt to impose your own rules, there's no guarantee that things will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `list.get(list.indexOf(fooObj))` isn't a workaround it's just how the `List` class is designed. You *can* add the *get(Object)* if you would like by inheriting from the `List` class, adding the method, and using your new type instead of `List`. But that seems like a lot of work to do for such a small benefit.

Comment: Can you recommend whats the best way to get an element from list in this situation?

Comment: Yes, exactly the way you did it. Use indexOf and then use get(index).

Comment: Yup. Need to do a null check every time. :(

Comment: @JavaEnthusiast Yeah... well it does say that in the Javadoc for the List class. But no worries, everyone makes those mistakes, it really never ends but it gets better lol.